# integrating asp.net core API with Angular app in host

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, web-config, web-deployment

I have done a web app project for my first practice which is written in two parts. The back-end is an API by ASP.net core and the front end is by Angular, they works prefect together in local but I've faced problem after deployment, in fact at the same time just one of them get started.

I used publish via **ftp** for asp and **ng build -- prod** for Angular development's. However, I changed *environment.prod.ts* and *ConnectionString* I'm sure they are correct.

extra info:
web.config in case just my API works and the angular part doesn't come up! I just can see HTTP ERROR 404 when I hit the URL, but the API works fine!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebAPIDecor.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\log1\stdout" hostingModel="outofprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

**my environment.ts:**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false
  ,
  baseApiUrl: 'http://localhost:57736/api/',
  wallPaperJournalUrl: 'WallpaperJournals',
....

};
```

**my environment.prod.ts:**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseApiUrl:   'https://myurl.com/api/',
  wallPaperJournalUrl: 'WallpaperJournals',
...
}
```

Comment: Can u hit even the landing page of your angular app on your production server?

Comment: having this web.config no unfortunately , but if I delete it my index will come up and also the API will crush!

Comment: so I solved problem by my-self!
I created a wwwroot folder in my project in the Visual Studio then I put all angular file(after building) in that folder then I publish the projects.